# Check WiFi and mobile data is active or not

Tags: android, wifi, mobile-data

In a android studio project I want to check active internet, for that I use this class. Its working but. problem is it only work when connection not available. But i want only return true when connection is active and workable. Because the app working with webview, and if connection is week or not active then its showing not reachable error. Its happening most with WiFi. Please help

```
public boolean isConnected(Context context) {

  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

  if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
  android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = 
  cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
  android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = 
  cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

  if((mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (wifi != null && 
  wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
  } else{
   return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: isConnectedOrConnecting() is enough, what would you check connexion type too ?

Answer (score -1):

This is what I am using in my working code:

```
public static boolean isOnline(){    
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Remember to add in your manifest the network state permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and, if you need to use internet in your application, consider adding also this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

you can also refer [to this link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) for the official documentation about network permissions
hope this helps

Comment: I want only return true or false

Comment: @Swister add in your manifest the first permision i mentioned and call the method i posted above to get true if you are online, false if you are not

Comment: your answer is wrong. Have u test the situation that both of wifi and 3g is enabled?